# Is a question a duplicate if it's the same as another one from the same author with a minimal difference?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A user asked a question (not the best question ever, not the worst either), and I answered it. The user didn't accept it or commented it, then posted a question *really* similar.   I would give almost the EXACT same answer, changing 2 lines of code.

The new question changed from activating/deactivating a button with a specific event, to hiding/showing said button with the exact same event. I do believe that this is enough to say it is a duplicate.

Comment: To me that sounds like a duplicate as it boils down to wanting to perform an action on a button based on an event and that action can either hide or activate the button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56484168/17034  It won't be so easy to convince a moderator, ideally she would have gotten an answer before that showed that disabling the button was the best approach.  You can still make that happen, if you have a way to get a decent event.  I'd guess that is the hard part.

Comment: I wouldn't know if disabling the button is the best approach, but from what I understand it is what she asked in here first post, made my answer in that way. I would pretty much duplicate my answer, it would even be simpler to just hide the button, it doesn't feel like much effort where done for the second question.

Comment: It appears that the author deleted the second question.

Comment: To be fair, I edited my answer to the first question making it simpler, yet keeping the same result : disabling the button, my answer was then accepted and the second question deleted.

Comment: Problem solved then.